# When inserting into one table, insert into others with the same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have 3 tables:

users, contact and pay_roll.

All of the tables share the column user_id which is the primary key and is auto incrementing on all of them, when I insert a new user into the table "users", is there a way to add a blank row to both contact and pay_roll to then be updated later?

My SQL query so far:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.users (fName, lName) VALUES ('Kieron', 'Oates')
```

Comment: Show your table structure

Comment: Use an `After Insert Trigger`

Comment: You could also leverage the OUTPUT clause and then insert the newly generated identity values to the other tables without using a trigger.

Comment: Consider only autoincrementing your `user_id` in your `users` table. And then with a trigger or output clause, you can grab the new id generated from the auto-incrementing and insert that into your `contact` and `pay_roll` tables.

Comment: Trigger is not right solution unless you need to insert all the time when you insert into that table... If it is scenario based then we might go for output

Comment: i have looked at OUTPUT clauses and i think that is the best way to go, how are they used in a simple way like this? i can only find big, complicated ones online

Comment: Is my answer complicated?

Comment: I just want to create an empty row with the auto increment in the other tables when a new user is added to "users", i dont understand what your answer is doing @KannanKandasamy

Comment: Updated an example in my answer to just insert into contact table by using the same userid from users table

Answer (score 2):

You can use output clause of insert and insert into another table as below:

```
declare @otheruser table (fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10))
declare @user table (fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10))

insert into @user(fname, lname)
output inserted.fname, inserted.lname into @otheruser
values ('Kieron', 'Oates')

select * from @otheruser
select * from @user
```

For empty rows you can use as below:

```
create table #contact  (userid int, fname varchar(10), addr varchar(10))
create table #user (userid int identity(1,1), fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10))
create table #pay_roll (userid int, pay money)

insert into #user(fname, lname)
output inserted.userid, null as fname, null as addr into #contact
values ('Kieron', 'Oates')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong; your schema is fundamentally flawed. The "child" tables contact and payroll are dependent on the user table and should NOT have an identity column used as the foreign key to user. Remove the identity property from these columns. And since it is apparent that you want to create a 1:1 relationship between user and each child table, then the user column in contact and payroll should be both primary key and foreign key.

And no - you do not add "blank" rows to be filled in later. Why? For one, you cannot really distinguish between a "blank" row and a non-blank row without making assumptions about the content of columns. This approach will only lead to tears and many many long hours of work at a later date.